# C# how to copy a file held inside a variable and paste it to different location?

Tags: c#

Goal:

I am trying to copy a file.. which is stored inside a variable.. and then paste it into another folder specified.

I have looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731042/12129150 but that did not help, as I have a path inside a variable.

Here is what I have tried:

```
// File path attached
private string filePath = null;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Get the path of specified file
            filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
}



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.Copy(filePath, @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\@filePath");
}
```

But that just saved it to desktop as `@filePath`

Comment: What is the difference between a variable with the value `"C:\Users\user\Desktop\@filePath";` and using the string literal `"C:\Users\user\Desktop\@filePath"`? There is none. Both are just strings. | "But that just saved it to desktop as @filePath" Wich is **exactly** what a copy target of `"C:\Users\user\Desktop\@filePath"` **tells** it to do.

Comment: This is a classic example of the code doing exactly what you tell it too. You've asked it to the copy the file at `filepath` to the location you provided and it did just that. What did you want it to do?

Comment: How do I correctly copy the file and paste it into another location?

Comment: Hello. You must to get the filename from path: File.Copy(filePath, @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\" + Path.GetFilename(filePath))

Answer (score 3):

Get the file name on its own

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var newPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop", fileName);
    File.Copy(filePath, newPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8) states that the second paramter is

> The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an
>   existing file.

So, you cannot pass a folder name as the second paramter.
You need to combine the original file name and the destionation folder and pass this value as the destination file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originalfile = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var destination = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\@filePath", originalfile);
    File.Copy(filePath, destination);
}
```